# javascript - does a click event fire on an element if it's not visible?

Tags: javascript, css, click, visibility, hidden

If you change the visibility of an element `visibility: hidden`, will a click event still fire if the user clicks it?

I want to "hide" an element (i.e. `<span>`) and disable the click event from firing, but retain is position in the normal flow of the document. So `display: none;` won't work since it removes the document from the normal flow, but was wondering what are my other options via CSS without actually handling the click event and using preventDefault()?

Comment: Did you try it out? What happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it won't fire when `visibility:hidden`, here is proof :)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFXC5/1/)

**JS**

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert('');
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.hidden {
    visibility:hidden
}
```

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer, in relation to his question... braid dead moment right there. I read it as 'no visibility hidden, will not disable the click event'.

Comment: This is how I can tell it's Friday... +1 for beating me to it, and for the clarification

Comment: and it's consistent in all major browsers (ff, chrome, safari, opera, and IE9,8,7)

Answer (score 2):

Yes visibility hidden disables the click event.

To test just right click a clickable element on this page with a web-kit browser, apply a style of `visibility: hidden` and you will be unable to click it.