# Delegated on click not working on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $(document).on('click', 'div.item_2', function(){
      alert('buy');
  });
```

the item exists on the page, anyway this should work no matter if the element exist or not, its a delegated click, but I can't understand why it not work on my:

```
<div class="item_2">
</div>
```

there are no event removers, where I should look to find a bug? cause I don't see any reason that it should not work...

Comment: Me neither. My guess would be: you didn't include jQuery.

Comment: @FelixKling, there are no other code to show, I'just don't know what to do...((

Comment: If there really isn't anything else to show then you haven't created a complete HTML document.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue with a jsFiddle or an SO code snippet?

Comment: Have you included jQuery? Where is this code, own file or in the HTML? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Try to break it: http://jsfiddle.net/6o4s1wfj/ and we might help you fixing it :)

Comment: Have you looked at the console to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: the jQuery is included, there are no errors on the console, I've tought that maybe is a browser problem...can't figure out

Comment: Does the `div` have any actual content that can be clicked on?  (Maybe a silly question, but the code provided *works* so the problem must be something else...)

Comment: add in html `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>`

Comment: the div was hidden, the delegated click was not fired on a hidden div...thank you

Answer (score 1):

A div that is not visible will **not** fire the click. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708418/javascript-does-a-click-event-fire-on-an-element-if-its-not-visible).

Comment: How do you know that the div is not visible?

Comment: oh you really have telepathy abilities, thats was my problem, thank you!! :DD

Comment: From what we see, that div has no size. That would make it not visible/not clickable.

Comment: @mmcrae: however, that's a different issue than what this answer is about.

Comment: @Huangism The phrase "the item exists on the page" made it sound like the div was in the markup, but not necessarily visible. Based on the issue, the div being invisible seemed likely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've included jQuery in the `<head>`?

Are you running on your local filesystem? If you copy and paste from jQuery from google:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It won't work on your local file system. You'll need to add http: to the url:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: According to the OP, he says jQuery is included and there are no errors.

Comment: Just because jQuery is included, it does not mean it's included correctly.